# How do I resolve this? (Error Incomplete expression stargazer)

Tags: r

*This came up
Error: Incomplete expression: stargazer(df_analysis[c("YRSCHOOL", "SCHOOL", "CHBORN_MOM", "AGE", 'CAPITALCITY", "NOINCOME_MOM", "NOINCOME_DAD", "MALE")], type = "text", summary.stat = c("n","mean","sd", "min", "max"), covariate.labels = c("Years Of Schooling", "School Attendance", "Number of Children", "Age", "Capital City", "Mother Has No income", "Father Has No Income", "Male"), digits = 2, title="Summary Statistics", notes="Note: Data are 1% sample of individual aged 5-21 from 1980 Thailand census. Source: IPUMS International")

Does anyone know whats wrong?

*I ran this
stargazer(df_analysis[c("YRSCHOOL", "SCHOOL", "CHBORN_MOM", "AGE", 'CAPITALCITY", "NOINCOME_MOM", "NOINCOME_DAD", "MALE")], type = "text", summary.stat = c("n","mean","sd", "min", "max"), covariate.labels = c("Years Of Schooling", "School Attendance", "Number of Children", "Age", "Capital City", "Mother Has No income", "Father Has No Income", "Male"), digits = 2, title="Summary Statistics", notes="Note: Data are 1% sample of individual aged 5-21 from 1980 Thailand census. Source: IPUMS International")

Comment: `'CAPITALCITY"` has mismatched quotes.

Comment: Please learn to use this sites possibiliries for code markup. As of now it is difficult to read your code